# How can i fix my p tag in media query

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add a media query, to my code. But when ever i tried to move my paragraph towards left, the text goes to the next line. How can i move the `<p>` tag to center?

Here is my Code :

```
     @media (max-width: 1023px ) and (min-width: 767px) {

               #pt {
                 padding-left: 300px;

               }
              #pet {
                text-align: center;
                padding-left: 200px;
                margin-bottom: 1.3em;
                padding: 1em;
                -webkit-column-width: 150px;
         -moz-column-width: 150px;
              column-width: 150px;

              }

             }

            </style>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center " data-wow-delay="0.6s">
                <div class="service-item">
                    <div class="service-icon">
                        <i   id="pt" class="fa fa-clock-o fa-5x"><br></i>

                    </div>



                    <h3  id="pt" style="font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">Project Tracking</h3>
                    <p  id="pet"  style="font-size: 16px;  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">
                        Obtain constant
                        updates on the progress of the project along with images and track your investment regularly
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Here is the result:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUOVD.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your `column-width` value is pushing text to the next line early. Increase it's size. Note I also commented a couple `padding`s to preserve center aligning.

[Check resizable JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/pfuLh0gh/)

[image]